# Not able to stack two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div style="margin-right: 13px; display: inline-block;">
            <h3>Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; position: relative;">
            <i>X</i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="horizontalDivider></div>
        <ul ></ul>
</div>
```

the issue is it('X') doesn't stay at the position right above the horizontal line.

I'm able to manage up to some extend with percentage, but it is causing in responsive style.

e.g [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/furqanms/qrphjs7y/), please resize the result pane and you will find the 'X' is wrapping to next line.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you provide a working demo of your problem? Preferably in a jsfiddle.

Comment: e.g http://jsfiddle.net/furqanms/qrphjs7y/ , Please resize the result pane and you will find the 'X' is wrapping to next line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use floating for this, a tabular layout will help you easily create the layout.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.header {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.title,
.close {
  display: table-cell;
}
h3 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title">
      <h3>Box title goes here and it can run on for longer than this single line could possibly contain</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="close">
      X
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following change has fixed my problem:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div style="**width:90%;** display: inline-block;">
            <h3>Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="**width:10%;** position: relative;">
            <i style="**float: right**;" >X</i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="horizontalDivider></div>
        <ul ></ul>
</div>
```